# URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher receive cancel

Tags: swift, combine

trying to fetch some data with dataTaskPublisher. however, constantly receive following log. it works every once in a while and not sure what's the difference. change URL does not make a difference. still only occasionally succeed the request.

> Test2: receive subscription: (TryMap)
>
> Test2: request unlimited
>
> Test2: receive cancel

```
class DataSource: NSObject, ObservableObject {

  var networker: Networker = Networker()

  func fetch() {
    guard let url = URL(string: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts") else {
      fatalError("Invalid URL")
    }
    networker.fetchUrl(url: url)
  }
}

class Networker: NSObject, ObservableObject {
  var pub: AnyPublisher<Data, Error>? = nil
  var sub: Cancellable? = nil
  
  var data: Data? = nil
  var response: URLResponse? = nil
  
  func fetchUrl(url: URL)  {
    guard let url = URL(string: "https://apple.com") else {
      return
    }
    pub = URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
      .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
      .tryMap() { data, response in
        guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
              httpResponse.statusCode == 200 else {
          throw URLError(.badServerResponse)
        }
        return data
      }
      .print("Test2")

      .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    sub = pub?.sink(
      receiveCompletion: { completion in
        switch completion {
        case .finished:
          break
        case .failure(let error):
          fatalError(error.localizedDescription)
        }
      },
      receiveValue: {
        print($0)
      }
    )
}
```

Comment: It does not look like the issue in the provided code. Which is DataSource's life-time? Where do you store it?

Comment: May be use async-await?

Comment: @Asperi you right on the data source lifetime. I was using a observedObject in the view owning data source. however, it deallocated right away. After I change to stateObject dataSource lived and dataTask finished

Answer (score 0):

add .store(in: &subscriptions)